# PHP: need json_encode() 5.3 functionality in 5.2

Tags: php, json

Long story short, client's hosting is using php 5.2.5 and i desperately need to use the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option with `json_encode()` that came with 5.3. Does anyone know some equivalent for that purpose? Point it out please.

Comment: @cletus if only we all had control over every hosting environment ever

Comment: ...i'm still on 4.2 /cry

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Casting as an object before encoding worked for me on 5.2.5:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);

echo json_encode($array);
// [0,1,2]
echo json_encode((object)$array);
// {"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}
```

And using PHP 5.3 yields the same output:

```
echo json_encode($array);
// [0,1,2]
echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// {"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}
```

You might also try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515925/php-problem-with-json-encode/1515957#1515957) from another thread. Not sure what your exact use-case is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP pear package to support json_encode on older versions of PHP. It seems to support encoded objects.

Checkout http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/