# Serializng and deserializing empty arrays to Dictionary/object

Tags: c#, php, json, json.net

I'm working on a Silverlight 3 application that has to communicate with a PHP 5.2.13 server app.
We're using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to finish the job, but I'm having some problems with Dictionaries.

I'm doing some experiments and trying to deserialize an object that contains a Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, Block> Table
{
  get { return m_table; }
  set { m_table = value; }
}
```

C# serializes properly and I'm happy with it, but on the PHP side, when serializing an equivalent object that has an empty `Table`, it won't work.

```
$this->Table = array();
```

The problem is that empty arrays, obviously, aren't considered an assoc array and so they are exported as `[]` instead of `{}`.

I thought of adding something like `'null' => null` to the array (force assoc) and then do some clean-up in the client, but I don't control the client C# objects neither I can constraint them to be nullable so... I'm stuck on this one ;)

Do you know of any solution?

Thanks for your time, very much appreciated :)

**EDIT:** To clarify, I can't control the structure of both, the C# and PHP objects.
On my test I've created an object which contains a dictionary but the hole object gets encoded at once.
Here's an over simplified version of it:

```
class Block
{
  public $X = 0;
  public $Y = 0;
  public $Name = '';
  public $Children = array();
  public $Table = array();
  public $Nested = null;
}
```

Where `Table` should be a dictionary and encoded as

```
echo json_encode( new Block() );
```

Comment: On the PHP side, are you using the built-in `json_encode` function, or some other library?

Comment: Ok, good. Check out my answer- I think it solves your problem :)

Comment: Edited my question, sorry for not clarifying it before ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag to force `[]` to become `{}`, like so:

```
$b = array();

echo "Empty array output as array: " . json_encode($b) . "\n";
echo "Empty array output as object: " . json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

The output:

```
[]
{}
```

Note that *without* this option on, only associative arrays are encoded using object notation.

**From:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

**EDIT**

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634009/php-need-json-encode-5-3-functionality-in-5-2), casting the data to an `object` before encoding it will work:

```
$b = array();
json_encode((object)$b);
```

**EDIT**

The way I would solve this is a little hackish, but it will work:

```
$block = new Block();

$json = json_encode($block);
$json = str_replace("[]", "{}", $json);

echo $json;
```

This searches the resultant JSON for `[]` and replaces it with `{}`. The only problem with this that you have to be aware of is if, for example, Name is `[]`. It will be changed to `{}`. You could get around this by parsing the JSON and reconstructing it, replacing `[]` with `{}` when it is not part of a string literal. But, you may be able to make the assumption that `[]` will never be part of a string literal.

Comment: @SimpleCoder Unfortunately it is only available on PHP 5.3 (unless I made a stupid mistake) but I tried and it complained about having more than 1 function parameter. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is, the array is contained inside an object already, which I don't control. Let me edit my question but I've voted up on yours ;)

Comment: I've posted a hackish solution. :)

Comment: Now it fails for arrays of objects (that I deserialize to List<Block>) but I might have to set something like 'arrays as objects'... I'm going to wait just a little bit for a less hackish solution, if you don't mind but I'll mark this as correct in case it doesn't happen. Thanks :)

Comment: `Now it fails for arrays of objects` - Could you post an example of this?

Comment: On C# I have `public List<Block> Children` and that expects an array like `Children:[]` and now it has `Children:{}` and fails. I was also thinking I could force all assoc arrays to add `'json_nan' => 'json_nan'` and remove it before sending the json. I was trying to do this without asking for changes outside my code but, might be the only way... what do you think? :)

Comment: You could modify my search-replace code to search for `table:[]` and replace it with `table:{}`. It's hackish, but hey, it could work

Comment: Or, actually it would be searching for `"Table":[]` and replacing it with `"Table":{}". Other than that, I can't think of any other solution other than asking the other people you are working with to change their code :)

Comment: Well, `Table` is a member on my test class but not on the many final client classes... the suggestion I gave works but I'd rather prefer something less hacky but, as you said, for now it works and others can keep working with it while I 'fix' any problems. I think I will return to your first hackish suggestion as soon as I understand how to change JSON.NET converters to load arrays as objects :) Marking yours as correct because for the specific question I put it fixes the problem and you were really helpful, Cheers

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help! If I think of anything else I'll post again. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the 2nd method by simplecode, which works in this case

```
<?php
$b = array(
    "a" => array(),
    "b" => (object)array()
);

echo "Empty array output as array: " . json_encode($b) . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'm also looking at this, great stuff hehe