# Display multiple records in json using php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have written a script to query a mysql database and encode the data in json format.

I have added `$encoded = json_encode($encodable[0]);` which removes the other `[ ]` brackets but then only displays 1 record. Is there a way to still remove those brackets but display for example every record that I am querying?

Sorry not sure how to describe the problem in a better way!

Comment: Provide some sample input and output.

Comment: Might be missing something here but if you remove the `[ ]` brackets without parsing the data surely the JSON will become invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the result set of the query as JSON? Or encode data that is being sent to the database??

$encodeable[0] is the first element of the array, so its clear that that is what will be encoded. Depending on the format of your data, `encodeable[0]` would be `[{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}]` by default as thats an indexed array with keys of 0,1,2...

If your goal is to just output the json as a JS object `{}`, instead of an array `[]` you can use `json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` which will encode indexed arrays as `{"0":"value"}` or `{"0":{"0":"value"}}` instead of just `["value"]` or `[["value"]]`. If that's not what you're after, you may just need to loop through each encodeable element of your array and encode that way (use a for loop)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Ok this is the code I am using could you tell me where I put JSON FORCE OBJECT? 


$encodable = array();

mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$encodable[] = $obj;
}

$encoded = json_encode($encodable);

echo $encoded;

mysql_close();

Comment: Thanks I have added that but now it just echos 

"ArrayJSON_FORCE_OBJECT"

Comment: o_O Sorry about that, somehow I put a dot instead of a comma lol; `$encoded = json_encode($encodable, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` (thats the reason why it says array, it was concatenating it)

Comment: Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

Comment: Ah... you need PHP 5.3.0 or greater to use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option... Try this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634009/php-need-json-encode-5-3-functionality-in-5-2) if you can't upgrade your PHP version. `json_encode((object)$encodable);`

Comment: Ok thanks that does work now. Just need to figure out how to get that into another system now! Thanks for all your help.