# How can I use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK at php under 5.3 version?

Tags: php, json, numeric

I'm actually getting this error at the server:

> Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

At the localhost it works perfectly. So i think that the problem is that the PHP version of the server is 5.2.

Is there a solution? Or another way to do it?

Comment: could this be your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515925/problem-with-json-encode

Comment: Warning: PHP 5.2 was declared end-of-life nearly four years ago, and has not had any updates since then, including security updates. It is known to be insecure and nobody should be running a production server with it today in 2013. You should contact the administrator of your server and ask why it hasn't been upgraded in all that time.

Comment: it's a free server... thanks anyway!

Comment: I just resolved the problem using (float) into the array. 
I can't resolve the question yet because my low reputation 
Thanks for all!